# Primer for Quantum Circuits and Optimization

Tags: circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

I am interested in studying physical systems and trying to build circuits to simulate them. Now, of course, all the systems I could try to work with at simple, toy, systems - and that's fine.

However, I find myself unable to fully grasp how to go from say, a hamiltonian, to a graph, and then to a circuit - let alone to successfully find the right framework to add optimization.

I am wondering: do you have any papers that do a good job in taking a beginner - besides Patrick Cole's paper - from first principles to quantum gates?

Thank you.